# Retry job when consumer dies using Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, queue, kafka-consumer-api

Can Kafka monitor the heartbeat of consumer and retry the job by persisting in the queue(Eventually sending it to a different consumer)?

Also I know that SQL table can be used as a queue for this purpose but can you please let me know the other options too?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, Kafka topics are persistent. If you're using consumer groups and committing offsets, then when a consumer of the group restarts/joins, it'll pickup at the last committed offset, yes. If that's not available, it'll use `auto.offset.reset` config position

Or you can disable Kafka-based commits, and store offsets in SQL database, sure, but Kafka does not provide this out of the box